# Access Polymer3.0 custom elements from static html

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x

I created a custom Polymer3.0 element. And it works fine when I do `ploymer serve`.

We  have an internal enterprise NPM registry, to which I published my element.

Now I want to use this element in a completely different project (which has only static HTML/JS) and is served by NGNIX server.

- Is this possible ? If so how to approach it ?
- Do I need to server my custom element via `node` or `http-server` for me to use in a static html in a completely different project ?
- Can we server the polymer3.0 elements like CDN, I saw some posts with `unpkg`, but for that I need to publish to global NPM. R there any other options ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue (in-fact it was me not looking at all the options in `polymer.json`).

If anyone is interested following is what I did..

- In my `ploymer.json` I added the following

  - `shell` property of json to point to my custom element js file
  - I also added to the `js` property, `"compile":true`..

Following is what my `polymer.json` looks like

```
...
"shell": "xxxxx.js",
"builds":[
{
  "name": "prod",
  "preset": "es6-bundled",
  "bundle":true,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "addServiceWorker": true,         
  "inlineCss": true,          
  "inlineScripts": true,      
  "rewriteUrlsInTemplates": true, 
  "sourcemaps": true,     
  "stripComments": true,     
  "js": {"minify":true, "compile":true},
  "css": {"minify":true},
  "html":{"minify":true}
},
...
```

I copied my files in `build/` folder to my `nginx` server and hosted them as regular folder. Of course I add `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;` to my `conf` file

In my static HTML to import my component all I had to do is

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@2.4.3/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
 <script type="module" src="http://XXX_MY_NGINX_VIRTUAL_HOST_XXXX/my-custom-element.js"></script>
```